# Save a page before leaving

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a basic HTML file by using HTML, CSS and javascript. Based on the user's input and specific actions, I've run methods to create elements(which alter the page). And when the user wishes to go to another page via the link in the page, I want to save the changes that are made in the page.

Note: I am using Google Chrome on Windows XP
And the method execcommand() does not work on Chrome

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you might want to look into `localStorage`....

Comment: You need to persist the state of your site for example in `localStorage`. You can detect when the user leaves your page with `onbeforeunload`. See more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What does "I want to save the changes" means???    Do you mean, save only the values or state or other?? And what you already tried??? Give some code snippet.

Comment: @FrayneKonok :
By saving the changes i mean, the state of the page.

I have a textarea where the user inputs some data and i have written a method to create a div element and post the data that the user has given in the textarea. And there are links to other HTML files in the same page. When the user leaves the page and navigates back to the same page, the created elements are gone

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do two things,

**first:** 
Detect when the user changes the page, at that time script for coping the page like:

```
var your_var = $(document).html();
$(document).load("new-page.html");
```

and then navigate a back button detection, when the user comes back to the first page just place your_var like:

```
$(document).html(your_var);
```

This is only applicable when your page navigation is done using only jQuery/ Ajax.

**Second:**

If you want to save state with server side scripting as well then use

```
javaScript.history();
```

this will give you the same page you left before with state.